# Redirect após update laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou trabalhando num projeto com laravel e me deparei com um problema. Após o Update eu quero redirecionar o usuário para uma outra página específica. Na função de update do meu Controller eu tenho esse código:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

    try {
        $exame = $request->all();

        $id_exame = Tab_exames::findOrFail($id);
        $id_exame->update($exame);

        return redirect()->route('agenda_exames')->with('success','Os dados foram atualizados com sucesso.');

    } catch (Exception $ex) {

        return redirect('agenda_exames')->with('error', 'Ocorreu um erro ao tentar atualizar os dados!'); 
    }        
}
```

Só que me retorna esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu usar esse redirecionamento não ocorre erro:

```
return back()->with(['success' => 'Os dados foram atualizados com sucesso.']);
```

Minhas rotas estão assim:

Redirect

```
Route::get('/agenda_exames', 'AgendaExamesController@index')->name('agenda_exames');
```

Pega os dados para a edição

```
Route::get('/edita_exames/{id}', 'AgendaExamesController@edit')->name('edita_exames');
```

Atualiza os dados

```
Route::put('/edita_exame/{id}', 'AgendaExamesController@update')->name('edita_exame');
```

Como posso redirecionar o usuário para outra página após o update utilizando os métodos apresentados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informa a *url* pelo *redirect*:

```
return redirect('/agenda_exames)->with('success','Os dados foram atualizados com sucesso.');
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback! Eu editei a pergunta, eu já possuo essa rota.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta. Qual versão do Laravel tas usando?

Comment: Estou utilizando Laravel 5.5. Testei com seu exemplo mas continua dando erro de rota.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Da uma olhada pra ver se vai redirecionar informando a url direto no redirect.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado.